# Too Localized to include "Not enough information"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, too-localized

Very very few questions currently get closed as "too localized". Which is fine, but I say we expand the definition of "too localized" to also include "not enough information".

Currently, when someone asks a broad question like "What kind of RAM do I buy?" it is closed as `not a real question` with comments saying "we need more information" that are upvoted like 20 times.

Currently, "not a real question" includes "incomplete":

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

I say we either introduce a "not enough information" close reason, or (more preferably)  moving it out of "not a real question" and into "too localized".

Comment: To which of the Trilogy sites are you referring?

Comment: Or are you proposing to roll "not a real question" into "too localised"?

Comment: I feel like "not a real question" is more for like when someone asks a non-subjective question that has no real answer. such as code-golfs that aren't CW.

Comment: @earlz: uhhhh.. "Not a real question" means that, well, it's not a real question. Code golfs **are real questions** and **can be answered**, they simply can have more than one valid answer. I read from the comment to my answer that now you want to move incomplete questions from "not a real question" into "too localized".. Well, those aren't real question. I think that the name of the close reason should have at least something to do with the reason, and basically you are proposing to close real questions as "not a real question" and close non-questions with "too localized".

Comment: i'm tempted to close this as "not a real question" ... ;)

Answer (score 4):

> It's difficult to tell what is being
>   asked here. This question is
>   ambiguous, vague, **incomplete**, or
>   rhetorical and cannot be reasonably
>   answered in its current form.

So using "Not a real question" is correct. I do agree that "Too localized" is the most useless and most abused* close reason.

*Most abused = The one used when you want to close a question because you think it should be closed even if, technically, it doesn't fall in any of the close reasons. It's the new "Blatantly offensive".

Comment: Hmm, I guess I should read more... Then I'm suggesting moving it out of Not A Real Question and into Too Localized.

Comment: I think that S&A is more commonly abused. Not that it matters that much - take away one reason and the just-hit-3k-goin'-on-a-closin'-binge crowd will simply choose a different reason to re-interpret.  Anyway, not-a-real-question is *definitely* the right reason for vague/incomplete questions.